# Why pandas places index name in a separate row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If I create a pandas dataframe without naming the index column, it prints the dataframe like this:

[image]

But if I rename the index column `df1.index.names=['letters']` and then print it, it prints it with the index name on a separate row, like this:

[image]

Is this by design and in this case why pandas does that?

Comment: It's just a way of presentation by pandas. Even after giving `index` a `name`, you can check the output of `df.columns`. It will be the same as before. So, it does not create a `hierarchical` column frame.